# How do I know which part of JavaScript is executed when some event is occurred

Tags: firefox, events, dom-events

How do I know which part of JavaScript that is executed when some event is occurred in Mozilla Firefox?

Comment: Install Firebux :)  https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/firebug/

Comment: Logging? Breakpoints?

Comment: I have firebug but which command I should use?

Answer (score 0):

This is a very broad question but I'll take a shot. I was a bit curious about the now native debugger in Firefox so I looked into this for you. Firebug is still a nice tool but you don't need it for debugging if you're running Firefox 19 or later. Let me also suggest trying Chrome's DevTools, they are my personal favorite.

To use the native debugger in Firefox, there's two options you will need to configure. Go to `about:config` (paste that in the address bar). Proceed past the warning. Update the following settings to be true (search is your friend):

```
devtools.chrome.enabled: true
devtools.debugger.remote-enabled: true
```

You need to do that so you can set breakpoints in the code. Now load the debugger, the shortcut is `Ctrl+Shift+S`.

At this point you need to have some idea where to set your breakpoints. If you wrote the JavaScript, you shouldn't have much trouble. If you're inspecting 3rd party code, you might need to browse the source code to get an idea where to begin.

With the debugger loaded, select a source file in the dropdown. It could be a JavaScript file, or any other resource that has JavaScript. You should open whichever file you're interested in inspecting.

To add a breakpoint, click to the left of the line number. You can also right-click on a given line and select "Add breakpoint." If you are debugging something that happens on page load, refresh the page. If it's an event handler, interact with the page to fire the event.

Those are the basics you'll need to get started with debugging in Firefox. Here are some resources you might need to go further.

MDN article: [Debugging JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Debugging_JavaScript)

YouTube video using FireBug: [Firebug DebuggingIntro](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ql7RFkZid_I)

Chrome DevTools: [Breakpoints in Chrome](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/scripts-breakpoints)

I hope that helps!